# EditText is overlapped by the toolbar on entering text

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a toolbar and TextInputEditText.
The TextInputEditText is inside the scroll view and the tool bar is outside of it.
When I enter the first text on the edit text the edittext box hides under the tool bar and nothing is visible while typing

This is happening only if i have more number of lines **android:lines="10"** for a small size screen. In a big screen it happens for lines greater than 20

I am pasting the layout code here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/addnote"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Lets_Note"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/addnote_title"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:hint="Title"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/daythemeicon"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/daythemeicon">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/addnote_title_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="10"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/addnote_descp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:hint="Notes"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/daythemeicon"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/daythemeicon">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/addnote_descp_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:lines="10"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
                    />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_bold_btn"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**View while textbox is clicked and text is entered**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumiv.png)

**The text which was entered and not visible**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs7Rl.png)

I tried to modify the reduce the number of lines and observed it was working fine.
later I have tried to handle it with different gravity options but that did not work.

I was expecting to add a layout constraint which can restrict the TextInputEditText to start after the toolbar ended but that did not work.